# how do I install quick.db

Tags: discord.js

i keep trying to install, and i just get this error message

```
 npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! > better-sqlite3@7.5.0 build-release
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!   symlink_builtin_sqlite3
npm ERR!   node:internal/fs/utils:345
npm ERR!       throw err;
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! CUSTOMBUILD : error : EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\deps\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' -> 'C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' [C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\locate_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!       at Object.symlinkSync (node:fs:1668:3)
npm ERR!       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\deps\symlink.js:18:5)
npm ERR!       at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
npm ERR!       at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
npm ERR!       at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
npm ERR!       at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
npm ERR!       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
npm ERR!       at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\deps\\sqlite3\\sqlite3.c',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Release\\obj\\global_intermediate\\sqlite3\\sqlite3.c'
npm ERR!   }
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   Node.js v17.8.0
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(245,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for '..\..\deps\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\locate_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=17.8.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.1.32319.34) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.8.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Monlo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.8.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Monlo\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\17.8.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-27T11_47_07_049Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT> npm i quick.db
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! > better-sqlite3@7.5.0 build-release
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!   symlink_builtin_sqlite3
npm ERR!   node:internal/fs/utils:345
npm ERR!       throw err;
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! CUSTOMBUILD : error : EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\deps\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' -> 'C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' [C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\locate_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!       at Object.symlinkSync (node:fs:1668:3)
npm ERR!       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\deps\symlink.js:18:5)
npm ERR!       at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
npm ERR!       at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
npm ERR!       at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
npm ERR!       at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
npm ERR!       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
npm ERR!       at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\deps\\sqlite3\\sqlite3.c',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Release\\obj\\global_intermediate\\sqlite3\\sqlite3.c'
npm ERR!   }
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   Node.js v17.8.0
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(245,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for '..\..\deps\sqlite3\sqlite3.c' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\locate_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=17.8.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.1.32319.34) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.8.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Monlo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.8.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Monlo\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\17.8.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Monlo\\Desktop\\CHAT REVIVE BOT\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Monlo\Desktop\CHAT REVIVE BOT\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Monlo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-27T11_59_01_032Z-debug-0.log
```

what do i do, ive been trying so many different things that ive found online, but nothing works, ive tried installing different versions of node, python, and even vscc, but literally nothing works, if anyone knows what to do, please tell me TvT

quick.db is kinda what i need to do everything for my bot rn, so im trying to get it done as soon as i really can

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm i quick.db` Here you can find more: (https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)